# APC with PHP 5.4

Tags: php, centos, apc

I'm facing some problem in using `APC` with `PHP`. I have installed `PHP 5.4.9` On my `CentOS 5.5` server machine. After that using `pecl` i installed `APC 3.1.9`. Then `apc.ini` was configured and all after, i tried `php -m` which lists `apc` module as loaded.

To counter check, the apc configuration, i also tried `php -r "phpinfo();"|grep apc` which produced and output as below

```
    Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/apc.ini,
apc
apc.cache_by_default => On => On
apc.canonicalize => On => On
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => Off => Off
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.file_md5 => Off => Off
apc.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
apc.filters => no value => no value
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.include_once_override => Off => Off
apc.lazy_classes => Off => Off
apc.lazy_functions => Off => Off
apc.max_file_size => 10M => 10M
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.num_files_hint => 1000 => 1000
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.report_autofilter => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867 => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867_freq => 0 => 0
apc.rfc1867_name => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix => upload_ => upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.serializer => default => default
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 64M => 64M
apc.shm_strings_buffer => 4M => 4M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.stat => On => On
apc.stat_ctime => Off => Off
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.user_entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.user_ttl => 0 => 0
apc.write_lock => On => On
```

I treied using `apc_store,apc_fetch` etc, in the code below

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','true');
flush();
//phpinfo();
echo "Stored in APC";
apc_store('KEY_a','data-stored',0);
$data = apc_fetch('a',$stats);
echo "Retreivin data: $data status:($stats)"
?>
```

This throws me an error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_store() in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/test.php on line 7`

This is all i did, any one find  anything wrong woth what i did? How can i make this thing work properly.? I tried many solutions including reinstallation. Fed up trying out. Can any one help?

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: By the way `php -i` is same as `php -r "phpinfo();"`

Comment: @WayneWhitty: yes i did.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your test in the **command line or browser**?

If it was in the command line it will not work as it's turned off.

```
apc.enable_cli => Off
```

If you ran the test on the **browser**, check the `phpinfo` on the browser and check that it's configured properly.

Comment: i use the apc in other servers with ubuntu and windows, there it worked fine. No im not using client.

Comment: When running `phpoinfo()` on the browser, do you see the apc options set correctly?